# Внедрение в контекстное меню android телефона

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли возможность внедрить в меню "Копировать вставить" свой пункт? При нажатие на который мы бы переходили с собственное приложение. [image: Пример]

Comment: Вы планируете вставить в "чужое приложение" некий пункт, который отправит вас в "свое" приложение?

Answer (score 2):

Есть такая возможность через [setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback%28android.view.ActionMode.Callback%29)